# is there a way to prevent iframe from redirecting the parent page without disabling flash

Tags: iframe

Im trying to prevent iframe from redirecting the parent page. i have tried sandbox but that also disables flash, but i need flash to be able to run in the iframe.

this is my code
also sorry about formatting this is my first ever time using the website

```html
<iframe id='iframe' sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-plugins" src='newideaplaceholder3.png' width='300px' height='146px'>
```